# Bootstrap/CSS: Layout issues inside 3-columns layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a full width row with 3 `col-lg-4`, each column with an icon, a title and a subtitle. But now I'd like to place the icon and text side by side, like this:

[image: Mockup]

Initial HTML:

```
<div class="cover-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="tile">
        <img src="" />
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div
    …
    …
  </div>
</div>



.cover-container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
}
.tile {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've tried with 8 `col-lg-2`, but I don't like that it shows each column as a row on a smartphone. 
I prefer to use 3 centered `col-lg-4`, but I can not place elements like in the mock-up,
can you help? Thanks…

SOLUTION:

```
<div class="cover-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sx-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 cover-tile-image">
                    <img src="/assets/images/1.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 cover-tile-text">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
            …
            …
    </div> 
</div>


.cover-tile-image {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.cover-tile-text {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :) with **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/qCpJ4/)**.

[Find here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) more information about the grids.

This solution is also RESPONSIVE READY.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row well">
    <div class="col-sx-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sx-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <img src="//placehold.it/50x50" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sx-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                 <h3>Title</h3>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <div class="col-sx-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sx-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <img src="//placehold.it/50x50" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sx-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <div class="col-sx-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sx-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <img src="//placehold.it/50x50" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sx-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
                 <h3>Title</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h3{margin:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I started with this solution with nested rows, added some styles to better fit my needs and combined with @cvrebert's suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to point out to y'all that:

```
class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"
```

is extremely redundant, and equivalent to the **much-simpler**:

```
class="col-xs-4"
```

I encourage y'all to read [Bootstrap's grid docs:](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any `.col-md-` class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a `.col-lg-` class is not present.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new in using bootstrap 3. Check the demo below I created. Hope this helps.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3021/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class=".col-xs-4 col-sm-4  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="tile">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/64/64" class="img-thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
             <h3>Title</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tile, .info {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns">
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns">
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
            </div>
            <div class="columns">
                 <h3>Title</h3>

                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.columns
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:110px;
    }
```

## Demos

---

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGqQM/15/)

[Result Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGqQM/15/embedded/result/)

---

## Output

---

[image]